# Scope issues with animateProperty in dijit

Tags: javascript, scope, dojo

In a custom dijit, I have a button with the `data-dojo-attach-event` hooked up to a method called `_goNext`.  I need to animate a node declared inside the Dijit controller javascript file, but it seems the scope of `animateProperty` is fudging things up a bit.

```
require([/* deps */], function(/*deps*/){
    return declare(null, {
    postCreate : function(){
        this._animNode = query('.someNode')[0];
    },
    // non-essentials omitted
    _goNext : function(){
        fx.animateProperty({
            node : this._animNode
            properties : { 
                left : { 
                    start : this._start,
                    end : this._end,
                    unit : 'px'
                } 
            },
            onEnd : function(){
                this.updateCurrentScreen();
            }
        }).play();
    }
} 
})
```

... is essentially what I'm working with.  As this goes, it does nothing, as it's scope is different than where my nodes and values are declared.  If I put values in manually (hard-coded) and apply an id for the node parameter to grab onto, it works fine, but that's silly and not what I'm after.

I've tried wrapping it in an anonymous wrapper passing `this` as the argument, but I'm getting TypeErrors with `style` and some other things.

Do I have to go as far as using hitch or some other variant of scope modifying method?  Or is there an easier way to have this thing ready `this` correctly.

Comment: Is it just a copy&paste mistake or do you have a huge syntax problem with mixing function and object literal?

Comment: Copy paste issue. If it was a syntax problem I wouldn't have gotten this far ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need to hitch your `onEnd` handler to the current value of `this`, otherwise you'll have context issues when you try to call `updateCurrentScreen`

Comment: Thanks!  It's easy to fudge things along without properly ensuring scope.